# WarpAffine function throwing error when using with openCL and opencv

Tags: c++, windows, opencl, opencv3.0

In one of of my opencv program i am using WarpAffine function to rotate images.This is how i used the function.

```
warpAffine(cropimage, imgRotated, RotateMatrix, cropimage.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

and its working fine

For improved FPS i tried to use GPU by using openCL
so i added these to the code

Added ocl header

```
#include "opencv2/core/ocl.hpp"
```

set the flag

```
ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);
```

change the data types

```
UMat cropimage,imgRotated;
```

then used the same warpaffine function

```
warpAffine(cropimage, imgRotated, RotateMatrix, cropimage.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

The program runs and in terminal am getting an error

[image]

[image]

My development environment is Windows7 along with visual studio 2012, the opencv version is 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find exactly what the issue is but the problem got fixed when moved to opencv version 3.1.0. Then it was not throwing any error. Also found that WarpAffine function is having memory leak in 3.0 which is also fixed in version 3.1.0